# Problema com foreach Carrinho de Compras

Tags: c#, asp, gridview, foreach

Estou a ter um problema com o `foreach` e gostava de saber se há outro método para não ter que alterar todo o código.

O que se passa é que cada vez que é adicionado mais que um produto ao carrinho, se comprarmos por exemplo 2 produtos em vez de ficar tudo na mesma encomenda, cada artigo fica em encomendas separadas, resumindo cada artigo fica com 1 ID de encomenda e não fica tudo na mesma encomenda.

Ou seja o que eu quero é que quando é feita uma encomenda com mais que 1 produto, e como é óbvio todos os artigos ficarem na mesma encomenda.

E isto deve-se ao `foreach`, há alguma forma de contornar isto?

Deixo o código aqui:

```
try
{
    foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtQuantcarrinho = (TextBox)di.FindControl("txtQuantcarrinho");
        int quantstock = oDB.ReceberQuantidade(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text));
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantcarrinho.Text) > quantstock)
        {
            int idencomenda = oDB.InserirEncomenda(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Iduser"]), "A aguardar produtos‏");
            oDB.InserirProdutoEncomenda(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text), idencomenda, Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantcarrinho.Text));
            int num = oDB.ApagarCarrinho(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Iduser"]), Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text));
        }
        else 
        {
            int idencomenda = oDB.InserirEncomenda(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Iduser"]), "A processar");
            oDB.InserirProdutoEncomenda(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text), idencomenda, Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantcarrinho.Text));
            int num = oDB.ApagarCarrinho(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Iduser"]), Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text));
        }

    }

    foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
    {


    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o problema é que você está inserindo a encomenda dentro do `foreach`, mas na verdade você deve fazer isso fora dele e dentro dele você adiciona apenas os itens da encomenda.

```c#
string estado = "A processar";

int idencomenda = oDB.InserirEncomenda(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Iduser"]));

foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
{
    oDB.InserirProdutoEncomenda(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text), idencomenda, Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantcarrinho.Text));
    int num = oDB.ApagarCarrinho(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Iduser"]), Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text));


    // verificar o estado conforme a quantidade em estoque
    TextBox txtQuantcarrinho = (TextBox)di.FindControl("txtQuantcarrinho");
    int quantstock = oDB.ReceberQuantidade(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[di.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text));
    if (Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantcarrinho.Text) > quantstock)
    {           
        estado = "A aguardar produtos";
    }
}
```

Depois de fazer isso, você deve alterar a encomenda novamente e setar o `estado` obtido dentro do `foreach`. Ou então, indicar esse estado em cada produto da encomenda.

Comment: @Issilveira só há um senão, o estado da encomenda fica sempre "A processar"...

Comment: O `int encomenda` precisa do `estado`, tive que colocar, por isso fica sempre "a processar".

`int idencomenda = oDB.InserirEncomenda(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Iduser"]), estado);`